# Python multiple inheritance of __new__ and __init__ with a string and second class

Tags: python, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, super, abc

I'm trying to create a derived class that inherits from both a `str` type and a second class. It's problematic since the `str` type doesn't simply call `__init__`, but the `__new__` method due to its immutability. I know that for `__init__` and super to work well, you need to have the same calling structure all the way down. However the following implementation fails:

```
class base(object):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print "NEW  BASE:", cls, args, kwargs
        return super(base, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print "INIT BASE", args, kwargs

class foo(base, str):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(foo, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(foo, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Here `foo('cat')` works with:

```
>> NEW  BASE: <class '__main__.foo'> ('cat',) {}
>> INIT BASE ('cat',) {}
```

but with an argument `foo('cat', x=3)`, it fails:

```
>> NEW  BASE: <class '__main__.foo'> ('cat',) {'x': 3}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "inh.py", line 19, in <module>
    foo('cat', x=3)
  File "inh.py", line 12, in __new__
    return super(foo, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
  File "inh.py", line 4, in __new__
    return super(base, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: str() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)
```

I *can* get this to work by changing the `base.__new__` method to:

```
def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    return super(base, cls).__new__(cls)
```

but now I've changed the calling structure, which I feel will cause me problems later down the line.

**How do I properly inherit from a string and a second class**?

Answer (score 3):

You can't just do

```
def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    return super(base, cls).__new__(cls)
```

because this will cause incorrect call for **new** of str (you will not pass allowed argument

```
>>> foo('t')
NEW  BASE: <class '__main__.foo'> ('t',) {}
INIT BASE ('t',) {}
''
```

You should do  something like

```
def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    return super(base, cls).__new__(cls, *args[:1])
```

But this can broken something if You will use `base` class as mixin for class which `__new__` method accept more than one argument.

as a option maybe You should have class inherited from `str` but with overridden **new** method:

```
class CarelessStr(str):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(CarelessStr, cls).__new__(cls, *args[:1])

class foo(base, CarelessStr):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(foo, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(foo, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: You're correct that my new doesn't pass the first argument. However your solution seems kind of painful, since it adds another layer of indirection. Admittedly it works, but is it considered the pythonic way?

Comment: I am not sure that there is generic solution for described task. I agree that this solution adds another layer of indirection. But this can be the only option for some cases.

Comment: Awesome. An extra str base hadn't occurred to me!