# What is the cause of the error during inheriting int class?

Tags: python

I ran this code

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, func) -> None:
        self.func = func

class B(A, int):
    pass

b = B(lambda t: t)
```

and got this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[40], line 8
      5 class B(A, int):
      6     pass
----> 8 b = B(lambda t:t)

TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'function'
```

What is the cause of the error? An empty class instead of int works.

+)

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, func) -> None:
        self.func = func

class C:
    def __init__(self, s) -> None:
        assert type(s) == str

class B(A, C):
    pass

b = B(lambda t: t)
```

this code works, so I am curious that what is special in int class, since the constructor never runs.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673651/inheritance-from-str-or-int and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16843158/python-multiple-inheritance-of-new-and-init-with-a-string-and-second-cla

Comment: Remember that when a class's `__new__` is implemented, it's called to return an object, and only after that is that object's `__init__` called. So if `B`'s `__new__` doesn't give an instance of `B` then `B.__init__` is never called.

Comment: Thank you so much!! Now I understood the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define `class B` to inherit from `class A` and from `int`. Class `A` constructs from a `function`,as stated in the `__init__` method, but `int` constructs from a number. When you try instantiate `B` with the `lambda` function, the `int` constructor raises a `TypeError`.
Are you sure you need B to inherit from both `A` and `int`?

Comment: -1 this answer misses what's actually going on here. It sounds like you're suggesting that all base class `__init__`s get with the same arguments for `C`, but that's not at all how Python works. If you replace `int` with a different "ordinary" type, then the OP's code would work _only_ `A.__init__` would be called.

Comment: @Brian61354270 Never talked about class `C` because it was an edit made after I posted my answer.

Comment: Whether the class is named `B` or `C` doesn't matter, this still isn't correct. You can following the links from slothrop in the comments above to learn about how object initialization actually works and why this behavior happens.

Answer (score -1):

The error occurs because you're inheriting from both class A and class int, leading to issues with the int constructor. If you want class B to have an integer value and inherit from A, consider using composition instead of directly inheriting from int.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).